# Joined SQL querie failed to populate dropdown

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to create a joined SQL query in order to populate an HTML dropdown but it does not seem to be working and I'm not sure why. I didn't get any error messages or anything. The drop-down simply wasn't populated. There definitely was information that is meant to be in the drop down it is not a problem with lack of data for the dropdown it is a problem with the code.

```
<select name="term3sport">
  <option value=" " selected disabled>Please select a third term sport...</option>
  <?php
  include_once('connection.php');
  try{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare(
      "SELECT DISTINCT Choices.Choice_ID, Sports.name
      From Sports
      INNER JOIN Choices ON Choices.Sport_ID = Sports.Sport_ID
      INNER JOIN Year ON Year.Year_ID = Choices.Year_ID
      Where Code Like CONCAT('%', :year, '%')
      AND Current='Y' AND (Sex=':sex' OR Sex='B') AND Term_ID='3' AND Year_ID=".$row['Year_ID']." ");
    $stmt->bindParam(':year', $_SESSION['year']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':sex', $_SESSION['sex']);
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
      echo("<option value='".$row['Choice_ID']."'>".$row['Name']."</option>");
    }
  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
    echo "error".$e->getMessage();
  }
$conn=null;
  ?>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Choices">
  </select>
```

Comment: Your code should be checking for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great stuff, almost right with that. After c.Choice_ID, s.name needed to be capitalised to s.Name. Also the last statement `y.Year_ID=".$row['Year_ID']." ");` was not needed as it was already covered the statement `INNER JOIN Year y ON y.Year_ID = c.Year_ID`.

My solution was:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare(
      "SELECT DISTINCT c.Choice_ID, s.Name
      From Sports AS s INNER JOIN Choices As c
      ON c.Sport_ID = s.Sport_ID INNER JOIN Year As y
      ON y.Year_ID = c.Year_ID
      Where y.Code Like CONCAT('%', :year, '%') AND
      c.Current = 'Y' AND
      c.Sex IN (:sex, 'B') AND
      c.Term_ID = 3 ORDER BY Name ASC");
    $stmt->bindParam(':year', $_SESSION['year']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':sex', $_SESSION['sex']);
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
      echo("<option value='".$row['Choice_ID']."'>".$row['Name']."</option>");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two obvious errors in the code, so I'll provide an answer.  I can't guarantee this fixes everything.

*Quality ALL column names when you write queries.*

In addition, you are passing values in as parameters, so you don't need single quotes.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.Choice_ID, s.name
From Sports s INNER JOIN
     Choices c
     ON c.Sport_ID = s.Sport_ID INNER JOIN
     Year y
     ON y.Year_ID = c.Year_ID
Where ?.Code Like CONCAT('%', :year, '%') AND
      ?.Current = 'Y' AND
      ?.Sex IN (:sex, 'B') AND
      ?.Term_ID = 3 AND   -- removed single quotes because I assume this is a number
      y.Year_ID=".$row['Year_ID']." ");
```

The `?` are placeholders for the appropriate table alias.  I don't know where the columns come from, so I can't add it in.  The last one, though, is used in the `ON` clause.  `Year_ID` is in at least two tables, so the reference is ambiguous.